# ¿Cómo obtener el ID de un formulario recién creado y autocompletarlo a otro en Django?

Tags: django, formularios

Lo que estoy intentando por ejemplo si tengo 3 modelos y de ellos cada formulario (forms), en mi template me gustaría que primero llene el formulario del Datos_representante y luego con el id que recién cree se autocomplete  en el form de AlumnoxForms, y con el id de AlumnoxForms se coloque en Alumnox_ficha. cabe destacar que tiene una relacion de ForeyngKey. Alguien que me ayude!! GRACIAS.

Model.py

```
class Datos_representante(models.Model):
    apellidos= models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Apellidos")
    
class Alumnox(models.Model):
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nombres")
    representante = models.ForeignKey(Datos_representante, verbose_name='Representante', default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Alumnox_ficha(models.Model):
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nombres")
    Alumnox= models.ForeignKey(Alumnox, verbose_name='Alumnox', default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class Datos_representanteForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Datos_representante
        fields = '__all__'
        
class AlumnoxForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alumnox
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude =  ('representante',)
class Alumnox_fichaForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alumnox_ficha
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude =  ('Alumnox',)
```

views.py

```
class repre_CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Datos_representante
    form_class = Datos_representanteForms
    template_name = 'pruebas/repre_CreateView.html'
    success_url = None

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance_model1 = form.save(commit=False)
        instance_model1.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('alumnox_CreateView', kwargs={'pk': instance_model1.pk}))


class alumnox_CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Alumnox
    form_class = AlumnoxForms
    template_name = 'pruebas/alumnox_CreateView.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('repre_CreateView')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance_model2 = form.save(commit=False)

        instance_model2.representante = self.instance_model1
        instance_model2.save()

        return super(alumnox_CreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance_model1 = get_object_or_404(Datos_representante, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        return super(alumnox_CreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance_model1 = get_object_or_404(Datos_representante, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        return super(alumnox_CreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Como pueden ver, en esta view yo puedo llenar los formularios en el template de forma seguida pero solo el Datos_representanteforms y alumnoxforms me falta el de Alumnox_fichaforms pero ahí no se como pasarle el id de alumnox y que se autocomlete, asi como sucede con el anterior.

Comment: Tu pregunta carece de detalles, considera añadir código

Comment: ya lo detalle mejor